# CodeIgniter 2.0.2:Processing Output

Tags: codeigniter

I use this Processing Output function _output(), it work very good with me, but in my controller some output like json, image, i wonn't proccessed by this function!!

so,How _output() function works only in specific type of header?

Comment: Which processing function? Where did you find it? Can you give example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_output, like _resolve is a catch-all (It's in the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) and I've seen it in the code). It will fire every time and there really isn't a way around that. It's sort of the point of those functions, actually.

You do have options, however, in what you'd like to do with the data once you have it, but then you are limited to either putting a private var in your controller (before you call view, you set a flag, `$this->_myFlag = 'BITMAP'` or something) or parsing output's parameter (that can get expensive fast).

After that, you're stuck out of luck.